# Что значит * в CSS?

Tags: css3, css

В некоторых шаблонах в файлах css я стал замечать в самом начале вот такую запись

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Что значит звёздочка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Универсальный селектор, соответствует любому элементу.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html